# generate_series -> subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same query level

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables:

sales

- id bigint
- invoice_number bigint
- stamping_id int (fk with stampings.id)

stampings

- id bigint
- invoice_from bigint
- invoice_to bigint

And i have this query:

```
   SELECT
    stampings.id,
    stampings.invoice_from,
    stampings.invoice_to,
    s.missing,
    sales.id
FROM stampings, (
    SELECT generate_series(stampings.invoice_from, stampings.invoice_to) as missing
) as s
LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.stamping_id = stampings.id
WHERE 
    stampings.id = 300000435
AND
    sales.invoice_number != ''
AND
    sales.invoice_number IS NOT NULL
AND
    sales.invoice_number = s.missing
LIMIT 100
```

The error:

> [Err] ERROR:  subquery in FROM cannot refer to other relations of same
> query level LINE 9:  SELECT generate_series(stampings.invoice_from,
> stampings.in...

What im expecting is, to get the missing invoice_number based on a specified range by the stamping

Comment: There is no point to the inner select.  You can just join directly to the function call without wrapping it in a select.  If you do wrap it in a select, then the join must be declared as LATERAL.

Comment: the data type of `sales.stamping_id` is better be `bigint` rather than `int` since it's type is `bigint` in stampings table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the derived table so that you can can use a lateral cross join

```
SELECT ...
FROM stampings
  CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(stampings.invoice_from, stampings.invoice_to) as s(missing)
  LEFT JOIN sales ON sales.stamping_id = stampings.id
```

As soon as the derived table is removed, the `lateral` is implicit.

Comment: `stampings CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series(...)` and `stampings , LATERAL generate_series(...)` and `stampings CROSS JOIN generate_series(...)` and `stampings , generate_series(...)` are all valid I think. When the function (generate_series) is directly in the FROM clause, the LATERAL is implied.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ: yes you are right. I like to be explicit about the joins I am writing

Comment: Yeah, agree on that. One difference between the `,` and `CROSS JOIN` (which is important in the specific query due to the LEFT JOIN) is that they have difference precedence over other JOINs. So in this case it needs to be CROSS JOIN, whether LATERAL is used or not.